# web.config rewrite not working for homepage

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, web-config

I have rules in my root web.config file to force trailing slashes and rewrite all URLs to the index file, as part of a Codeigniter setup. It all seems to work except for on the homepage, where the server (rather than Codeigniter) throws a 404 error.

Weirdly, it only does this on the live website, it works fine on my local setup (which is identical to the live one).

My web.config file is in the root directory, along with the index file, and contains the following rules;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Force trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Remove index file" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

How can I determine what is causing this on the live site, or is there just something I need to change in my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

try this it's working for me!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```